# Why dynamic languages don't guarantee the state of an object?

Tags: design-patterns, dynamic

I have come across the description of the memento design pattern:
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento

At the bottom of the page in the *'Pros and Cons'* section, the author 
states:

> Most dynamic programming languages, such as PHP, Python and
>   JavaScript, can’t guarantee that the state within the memento stays
>   untouched.

Basically it says that if you do nothing with the Object(Mement) then the member(State*) can change? 
Does this mean that the state of an object can change randomly? If so why?
I am bit lost on this.

*Dont confuse it with the 'state' I have used in the title.

Comment: I guess that's referring to the fact that there's no build-in functionality in the language to make memento object immutable. You can still create immutable value objects tho, you cannot just enforce that from the language itself.

Comment: That quote seems to conflate dynamic typing with mutability. Not sure why that is. Even in statically-typed languages like Java, serialization is typically performed via reflection, which ignores encapsulation anyway.